# Probability Generating Function of the difference between 2 Poisson random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have 2 Poisson random variables, X and Y where X ~ Poisson(a)
and Y ~ Poisson(b). What would be the probability generating function of X - Y then? I think the first step is to realize that this probability generating function = E[$z^{X-Y}$] = E[$z^X$]E[$z^{-Y}$]. However, I cannot proceed any further after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Otherwise you cannot say that $Ez^{(X-Y)}=Ez^{X}Ez^{-Y}$ and, in fact, you cannot compute the generating function of $X-Y$ at all.

$Ez^{X} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-a} \frac {z^{n}a^{n}} {n!}=e^{-a}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {(az)^{n}} {n!}=e^{-a+az}$. Similarly compute $Ez^{-Y}$.

Comment: Could you kindly inform me what would $Ez^{-Y}$ be please?

Comment: It is $e^{-b+\frac b z}$.

Comment: One final question, please, could you kindly show me why $Ez^{-Y}$ is equivalent to the expression you provided?

Comment: $Ez^{-Y}$ is same as $Et^{Y}$ with $t=\frac 1 z$. So all you have to do is use the calculation of $Ez^{X}$, change the parameter from $a$ to $b$ and change $z$ to $\frac  1 z$.

Comment: Thank you so much!